# better way to write a csv into a StringIO from another StringIO object

Tags: python

I have the following stringIO object:

```
s = io.StringIO("""idx  Exam_Results    Hours_Studied
0       93          8.232795
1       94          7.879095
2       92          6.972698
3       88          6.854017
4       91          6.043066
5       87          5.510013
6       89          5.509297""")
```

I want to transform it into a csv format and dump it into a new stringIO object. I'm using currently this strategy to do that, but to me it seems I bit clumsy.

```
output = ""
for line in s.getvalue().split('\n'):
    output += re.sub(r'\s+',',',line) + '\n'


output = io.StringIO(output)
print(output.getvalue())
```

**Result:**

```
idx,Exam_Results,Hours_Studied
0,93,8.232795
1,94,7.879095
2,92,6.972698
3,88,6.854017
4,91,6.043066
5,87,5.510013
6,89,5.509297
```

Is there a clever way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv module:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO


s = StringIO(
    """idx  Exam_Results    Hours_Studied
0       93          8.232795
1       94          7.879095
2       92          6.972698
3       88          6.854017
4       91          6.043066
5       87          5.510013
6       89          5.509297"""
)


def convert(origin: str) -> StringIO:
    si = StringIO(newline="")
    spamwriter = csv.writer(
        si, delimiter=",", quotechar="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )
    for line in origin.splitlines():
        spamwriter.writerow(line.split())
    return si


def main():
    sio = convert(s.getvalue())
    print(sio.getvalue())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why not use `csv.reader` as well? You can simply pass the original `StringIO` object as the file-like argument it expects.

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

text = StringIO("""idx  Exam_Results    Hours_Studied
0       93          8.232795
1       94          7.879095
2       92          6.972698
3       88          6.854017
4       91          6.043066
5       87          5.510013
6       89          5.509297""")

output = StringIO('')
writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(csv.reader(text, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True))
print(output.getvalue())
```

Output:

```
idx,Exam_Results,Hours_Studied
0,93,8.232795
1,94,7.879095
2,92,6.972698
3,88,6.854017
4,91,6.043066
5,87,5.510013
6,89,5.509297
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pandas` package

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

s = io.StringIO("""idx  Exam_Results    Hours_Studied
0       93          8.232795
1       94          7.879095
2       92          6.972698
3       88          6.854017
4       91          6.043066
5       87          5.510013
6       89          5.509297""")

out = io.StringIO()
df = (pd.read_csv(s, delim_whitespace=True)
      .to_csv(out, index=False, sep=';'))
```

```
print(out.getvalue())

idx;Exam_Results;Hours_Studied
0;93;8.232795
1;94;7.879095
2;92;6.972698
3;88;6.854017
4;91;6.043066
5;87;5.510013
6;89;5.509297
```